# How we can design best optimized solution: Generate huge random numbers and check in database table whether this numbers are there or not

Tags: mysql, optimization, java, iseries, random

We have one table like:

Table Name:

```
random_number_series
```

Its columns are as below:

```
number      [numeric(10)]
name        [varchar(10)]
status      [tinyint(1)]
type        [tinyint(1)]
createdDate [datetime]
```

This table have around 250-300 million rows.

Now our requirement is that we will generate random numbers in big quantity i.e. 1 million. We want to check that this generated numbers are there in above table (with number column) or not.

How best we can do this?

Note:

-> Random numbers will be generated in application logic.

-> I want to know strategy / pseudocode how best we can design?

Comment: What will you do when you find some are present?  Or do you need to add exactly 1M; that is, you need to "keep trying" until you find enough new numbers?  Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Put the million numbers in a table.  Then `JOIN` the tables together to see which ones exist.  Or `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` to see which are missing.

Comment: Yes this one is in mind, will try this one as well. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is your random_number_series table fairly static?  Is the number sequence fairly fragmented?

If yes to both, my first thought was that it may be more efficient to store a "Gaps" table in your sequence.

random_number_series_gaps (
gap_start_number
, gap_end_number
)

```
If exists 
(
select * from random_number_series_gaps
where @randomNumberFromMyApp between gap_start_number and gap_end_number
)
SELECT 'Random number does not exist!'
```

Comment: maintaining gaps table is not seems feasible.